# QR scanning using raspberryPi camera nodeJS

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, qr-code, image-scanner

I am creating a nodeJS application that can be used to scan QR code on the raspberry Pi3 board.
I am able to successfully use a USB camera and scan the QR code using the Instascan node module.
However, when I try to use the Raspberry pi Camera, the Insta scan is not able to find it and not able to show the camera.
I have found many such options using python and OpenCV, however not with node js or electron.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: will you add your code and errors what you are getting?

Comment: No error, its just that instascan does not recognise it as camera

Comment: then you have write some code I guess? please add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is resolved.
Actually by default rpi camera is not shown in /dev/video list
so I had to enable V4L2 driver by

```
modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

This made CSI camera list in /dev/video list and application started detecting RPI camera.

Thanks everyone